# How to prove vacuous quantifier

Tags: first-order-logic, quantifiers, derivations

$ \exists x (Fx \rightarrow \forall x Fx) $

I am trying to construct a derivation for this problem which can be found in the UCLA logic software program under chapter 3 of the derivation section.
Up to this point in quantifier logic, anytime I had to prove an existential statement, there were either premises available to help derive the conclusion or the conclusion itself was an open conditional so I was able to assume the existential and just focus on proving the consequent.

However, in this case, it is a closed statement that has a conditional in it so I cannot assume the antecedent, nor is there a premise. lastly, i cannot apply quantifier negation to frame it as a universal statement. I am just completely stumped on this so any tips or suggestions or maybe even reference to resource will be helpful.

my derivation stops after the second line.

1. Show $ \exists x (Fx \rightarrow \forall x Fx) $
2. $ \space\space\space\space   \neg  \exists x (Fx \rightarrow \forall x Fx) \space\space\space assume \space indirect $

Comment: If you have an excluded middle / TND axiom, I think $(\forall xFx) \lor \lnot(\forall xFx)$ is a helpful start.

Comment: what do you mean by excluded middle?

Comment: ok i just saw TND axiom i will check it out

Comment: so the problem here is that if it wasnt quantified and was simply an instance or propositional logic i can apply negation of condition to get Fx ^ ~Fx however i just realized this is the first time im dealing with a conclusion that is restrictive in almost every respect. no premise, no applicable rules, and the conditional inside the conclusion has a quantifier itself

Comment: This is known as the Drinker's Paradox.

Comment: @Shaun but this is a bit different from drinkers paradox because the universal Fx cannot be treated as a distinct nonempty set P

Comment: It is exactly the same as the drinker's paradox.  "Fx" = "x drinks".

Comment: yes. u guys r right. its exactly like it lol. i was just so focused on specifics and memorized rules and that causes my approach to sometimes be very rigid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\forall x Fx$, then any element works as a witness to prove the desired statement. On the other hand, if $\lnot\forall x Fx$, then there is an element $m$ such that $\lnot Fm$, and this element works as a witness.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145650/discussion-between-swordlordswamplord-and-karl).